# Django lookups with m2m and intermediate (through) models

Tags: django, django-queryset

I've the following django models:

```
class RiskOf(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'catégorie'), related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(_('nom'), max_length=200)

class WorkingPlace(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(_('nom'), max_length=200)
   risks = models.ManyToManyField(RiskOf, through='WorkingPlaceRisk', verbose_name=_('risques'))

class WorkingPlaceRisk(models.Model):
    working_place = models.ForeignKey(WorkingPlace, verbose_name=_('poste de travail'))
    risk_of = models.ForeignKey(RiskOf, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u'risque DE avérés'))
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (1, _(u'éliminé')),
        (2, _(u'réduit')),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(_(u'état'), max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    chsct = models.BooleanField(_(u'enquête chsct'))
```

Given a RiskOf object (let's call it MYRISK), I need to retrieve all WorkingPlace objects which have at least one risk equal or descendant to MYRISK **AND** with the flag chsct set to True.

I know I can use this:

```
wplaces = WorkingPlace.objects.filter(workingplacerisk__risk_of__in = MYRISK.get_descendants(include_self=True))
```

to retrieve all WorkingPlace objects which have at least one risk equal or descendant to MYRISK, but I cant' find a way to "implement" the second condition I need, written in an horrible and clearly incorrect way I need something like (just to explain better what I need)

```
wplaces = WorkingPlace.objects.filter(workingplacerisk.filter(chsct=True)__risk_of__in = MYRISK.get_descendants(include_self=True))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `workingplacerisk__chsct = True, workingplacerisk__risk_of__in=...` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wplaces = WorkingPlace.objects.filter(workingplacerisk__risk_of__in = MYRISK.get_descendants(include_self=True) , workingplacerisk__chsct = True)
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I thought that this way I would retrieve also a case like this: consider a working place which has 2 risks, the first (1) which is a descendant of MYRISK and the second (2) which is not, where 1 has the chsct flag set to False and 2 set to True. I have to exclude a case like this and your answer does it correctly, while I thought it would retrieve this workingplace example too.